# sqlite3 NSDictionary memory leak

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdictionary

I have my sqlite execute query code as below.  Instruments catches a memory leak in the NSDictionary alloc and release lines (inside the while loop). Can someone point out what is wrong in those alloc/release ?

```
- (NSMutableArray *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql arguments:(NSArray *)args {
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStmt;

    if (![self prepareSql:sql inStatament:(&sqlStmt)])
        return nil;

    int i = 0;
    int queryParamCount = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(sqlStmt);
    while (i++ < queryParamCount)
        [self bindObject:[args objectAtIndex:(i - 1)] toColumn:i inStatament:sqlStmt];

    NSMutableArray *arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // instrument marks leak 0.1 % on this line
    NSUInteger rcnt= arrayList.retainCount;
    int columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(sqlStmt);
    while ([self hasData:sqlStmt]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  // instrument marks leak 13% on this line
        for (i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
            id columnName = [self columnName:sqlStmt columnIndex:i];
            id columnData = [self columnData:sqlStmt columnIndex:i];
            [dictionary setObject:columnData forKey:columnName];
        }
        [arrayList addObject:dictionary];
        [dictionary release];// instrument marks leak 86.9 % on this line
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStmt);
    rcnt=arrayList.retainCount;
    return arrayList ;
}
```

Any help/pointer is very much appreciated. Have been struggling with this for few days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ARC then I suggest you change your return line for:

```
return [arrayList autorelease];
```

Otherwise you are probably leaking the complete arrayList.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  When I try autorelease on arraylist, the program crashes with "message sent to deallocated instance".  Does that mean that I am releasing the arrayList somewhere else?

Comment: Probably means you are no retaining/releasing property outside your executeQuery:arguments:

Check that you are retaining the array returned by the function and that you are releasing it when you are done.

autoreleasing the return value is the correct action in the function. Therefore the error is likely to be outside the shown function.